# "no XML content. go to outline view and add nodes." problem in eclipse (indigo), linux

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

I've just moved my entire development suite from windows to linux. Huuray.
I have installed the entire android sdk on my laptop, and the ADT works great.
The only problem that I have is the above written text in my main.xml layout window, and I do not know how to view the layout itself. On top of it, I don't see the UI pallet.
I have deleted and reinstalled the entire eclipse\SDK\ADT sevral times, but I just can't get to view my UI pallet.

Did someone encounter this problem? if so, I'd love to hear how you solved it.

Thank you,
dan.

Answer (score 0):

> The only problem that I have is the above written text in my main.xml layout window, and I do not know how to view the layout itself.

If you are seeing this message, then there is no layout yet. You can drag something from the tool palette into the drag-and-drop area of the "Graphical Preview" sub-tab, or click on the "main.xml" sub-tab (below the editing area, above the console, in a typical Java perspective tools layout) to work with the raw XML.

> On top of it, I don't see the UI pallet.

AFAIK, that is not removable. It will be to the left of the drag-and-drop area in the "Graphical Preview" sub-tab:

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

If your Eclipse looks substantially different, perhaps posting a screenshot of your own will help us give you more concrete advice.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your kind answer!
I really do not have the pallet view in the eclipse (I've added a screen shot of the main.xml file), but as can be seen in the emulator (second picture added), there is a layout.
I don't know how this can be, I've checked various parts of the SDK installation, but its probably not related. sorry, since I'm a new user, the system doesn't allow me to upload images.

Comment: Use the Open With context menu of the XML file to make sure you're opening the file with ADT's layout editor and not the regular XML Editor.  The message about there not being any nodes is typical for the regular XML Editor's Design page when opened on an empty file.